# Windows XP -"Open terminal here" shell extension?

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, shell-extensions

I remember in Ubuntu, I think it was Gnome, Nautilus had this option in the right-click context menu that allowed you to open a terminal whose working dir was the dir you were visiting in Nautilus, not the default '/home' dir. Is there any way to get that kind of functionality in Windows XP?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need any tool to do this. Just a small Registry hack

Open a new file and paste this content, save as *.reg file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\cmd]
@="Open Command Prompt Here"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\cmd\command]
@="cmd.exe /k pushd %L"
```

And then double click into this file. Here we go!

Comment: Yeah, but I always hate to tell people to edit their registry without knowing their knowledge level ahead of time.  By any chance, is there a complimentary registry hack to remove these keys?

Comment: To delete a registry key with a .reg file, put a hyphen (-) in front of the RegistryPath in the .reg file

Comment: +1 I have a bunch of .reg saved away with shell hacks but it was quicker to find it here. Worked like a charm. It would be great if you added the remove reg file for newbs who don't know how to modify the reg.

Comment: It looks like it works no matter where you save the file - I just tested it.

Comment: Yes that's right. Save it wherever you want, run it and delete it after use.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work when I right-click on the background of a folder that I'm already in? (As opposed to right-clicking on a folder icon, which is what your current solution enables.)

Answer (score 7):

Probably the simplest way is to use the [Microsoft Power Toys](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) - there is a [CmdHere.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/whistler/Install/2/WXP/EN-US/CmdHerePowertoySetup.exe) specifically to do this.

Answer (score 6):

I know this question is about Windows XP, but this is a sidenote:

These methods are unnecessary in Windows 7. In this version <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>Right-click</kbd> allows access to a context menu with additional options, including open terminal here (more detail at [download squad](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2009/02/09/windows-7-tip-elevated-command-prompt-anywhere/)). Also holding down <kbd>Control</kbd> will open it with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 0):

[xpy](http://xpy.whyeye.org/) can add this to the Explorer.

> Supporting Windows 2000, Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, xpy
>   allows tweaking the default settings to your needs. This includes the
>   disabling of services, changing the behaviour and usability, deleting
>   undesired files, or tweaking programs like Internet Explorer, Windows
>   Media Player and Windows Messenger.