# Stop command prompt closing on crash on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

Whenever a program in command prompt crashes on Windows it closes so fast that I can't see the error message that is displayed in the prompt. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

There are two different situations where this occurs. One is when I open a program I downloaded from the Internet. This is solved by opening up a prom[t first (although it is a pain to have to open a prompt and type in the address of the application.

The other case is when I am using an IDE. I use a variety (Eclipse, Netbeans, Visual Studio, ect). Perhaps I should ask this part of the question on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific as to which application you are running at the command prompt that is crashing?

Comment: I've had this problem with various applications for years. Sometimes its a standalone program, sometimes its a program I wrote myself within an IDE

Comment: Just to clarify, as this is relatively often misinterpretation. Is the cmd crashing (you get a windows dialog: cmd has crashed ... send error report ...) or are you executing some program in it and it executes so fast and then closes, that you cannot see the result of the program ?

Comment: @Idigas: I should have been clearer. The application is crashing, not the prompt.

Comment: So, it is a command line application? And the error message shows where ? In the cmd ? When it crashes, I would expect for the cmd to remain open.

Comment: In any case, as to save time, could you elaborate a little on the matter, in view of details (which application/what kind/what crashes/where is the error mess. supposed to show etc. etc.) ?

Comment: I think what you may be doing here is opening an executable from explorer. Try opening up command prompt and then running it from there by typing for example `C:\myprogram.exe` rather than clicking on myprogram in explorer.

Comment: @Idigas: Updated the question again

Comment: @Casebash ... ah, it is clear now. But Jonathan already beat me up to it ...

Comment: Here's a bunch of workarounds, but no one has a solution: http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000738.htm  It should really pause by default when the command prompt is finished, and allow you to read the error.  Is there any way to make this happen with *all* command prompts?  Can the command prompt executable be replaced with something nicer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any program you can just open a command prompt and run the program from there; that's the obvious way.

If you're writing a program yourself you can put a `Console.ReadLine()` or so at the end which won't close the console window until <kbd>Enter</kbd> is hit. It's not too nice, though, so probably wrapping it into `#ifdef DEBUG` makes it nicer.

Anyway, for Eclipse it shouldn't be really necessary as Eclipse captures the console output of the program it runs (at least it does it for me with Java).

For Visual Studio you may consider using `Debug.Print` instead of `Console.WriteLine` for lines you really want to see.

For all cases of an own program you can also just dump crash information into a file.

Comment: If manually entering the path of the program is too painful we can use the method here: http://superuser.com/questions/98322/windows-xp-open-terminal-here-shell-extension/110199#110199

Comment: While a configuration setting to stop the console closing on error would be ideal, this solution is good enough to be workable.

Comment: @Case: Well, the problem is that the console window is tied to the process. Once that process terminates, the window disappears, just as a GUI window disappears if its owning application closes. That's actually a design choice I think. PIF shortcuts in Windows 9x behaved otherwise and *could* be told to remain open after the program exited. But that was an entirely different thing architecture-wise. Visual C++ 6 apparently automatically ran the program with `cmd /c foo.exe && pause` so there was a prompt at the end. Something I actually liked but VS2k8 doesn't have such an option. Sadly.

Answer (score 1):

If (as it appears to me) you're running a program which opens a console window when it runs (and which is therefore closed when the program exits) then you need to find a way of running it from an existing Command Prompt window.
The program may still open another console window and crash, but you might get to see some output in your Command Prompt window.

Comment: This is my situation.  I run the program from the command line, the program opens another command prompt, which immediately closes with an error I can't read.  The command prompt that remains open doesn't show any errors.